# How to upgrade latest version of my application without uninstall the old version manually?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, upgrade, installshield, installshield-le

I have my project in visual studio and i am using installshield as my windows installer. When I am installing new updated version of my application it will shows

> Another version of this product is automatically installed like this...

How can I install new version by overwriting my old version?

Is there any way to configure in installshield or give me any other way
?

Comment: Is the quoted text an actual error message? If so, is that really what it says?

Comment: "Another version of the product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of the product, use Add\Remove Programs on the Control Panel." like this

Comment: Please update your question to fix the error message.

Comment: I'm developing one product in visual studio, I'm using installshield as windows installer. I want to do minimum upgrades like 3.1.1 to 3.1.2 without uninstall existing version "manually" . How Can I configure in installshield update automatically for next versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under The `Upgrade Paths`, create a new path. Leave the min version blank (unless you need it), include min version yes, Max version should be set to the version You are installing now. Include max version to yes.

Each time you are installing an update, Increase the Product version(If u want to change) in the General Information section. Click on a new Product Code in the General Information Section `Do not change` the upgrade code.

Go back to the `upgrade path`, and set the Max version to the same version you are deploying now.

And make sure the `Upgrade code` in the "General Information" and "Upgrade path" are same.

This process uninstalls previous version, and installs the latest. No duplicates in add/remove programs.

If any doubt on this, comment your question...

Answer (score 3):

The error that you're getting is because the ProductCode has not been changed. This code is what makes your product/installer unique. Generally to author the upgrade you'll need to change this code and make sure the UpgradeCode is the same so that it recognizes what is already installed.

Authoring upgrades is a much wider topic and far too much information then can be covered here. I would suggest this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx) for learning about Windows installer upgrading.

Comment: If I change my product code another version of my product exist separately, But I want to uninstall existing version and install new version while installing my new version like 3.1.1 to 3.1.2. Without Uninstalling the existing version manually

Comment: What you describe is a major upgrade. Follow the documentation for how to perform this and the MSI should automatically uninstall your old version.

Answer (score 0):

Every upgraded version of install should have a different ProductCode.  UpgradeCode is what tells the install package that this product has been installed.  If ProductCode is also the same, install assumes you are installing the same product again.  ProductCode needs to be different for each of the updated packages.